# Find the largest possible value of $x+y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> It is given that $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and
> $$(x-2004)(x-2006)=2^y$$ Then find the largest possible value of $x+y$.

Let $2004\cdot 2006=A$ Then

$$x^2-4010x+A=2^y\implies$$
$$\log_2(x^2-4010x+A)=y$$
Now we have to maximize
$$f(x)=x+\log_2(x^2-4010x+A)$$
Taking the first derivative, I got
$$f'(x)=1+\frac{2x-4010}{\log_2(x^2-4010x+A)(\log_{10}2)}$$ Now doing, $f'(x)=0$ I got two values of $x$ from wolframalpha (it indicates that my method is exceedingly incorrect) but none of them gave the right answer.

I want a solution involving least calculus. Also, I don't prefer a solution using lagrange multipliers, simplex and linear programming. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\log_2(a)$ is really $\frac{1}{\ln 2}\ln a$. That will aid your differentiation... certainly I shouldn't be seeing $\log_{10}$ in your workings. The correct expression for $f'$ is: $$f'(x)=1+\frac{1}{\ln 2}\frac{2x-4010}{x^2-4010x+A}$$Which equals zero iff. $\ln(2)(x^2-4010x+A)=4010-2x$, iff. $\ln(2)x^2+(2-4010\ln2)x+A\ln2-4010=0$. This is a horrible quadratic. Its roots are: $$x_\pm=\frac{2005\ln2-1}{\ln2}\pm\frac{1}{\ln2}\sqrt{(2005^2-A)\ln^22+1}$$

Comment: @FShrike That's a real intimidating expression....btw ${2005}^2-A=1$

Comment: Hopefully this gives the right answer: note that the solution calls for $x,y \in \mathbb Z$, so in particular $(x - 2004)(x - 2006)$ has to be an integer power of 2; but since $x - 2004$ and $x - 2006$ differ by just 2, one of them must exactly be 2. This leaves us with two cases, namely $x - 2004 = 0, x - 2006 = 2$ and $x - 2004 = 2, x - 2006 = 4$. Clearly the latter case gives a bigger sum of $x + y$, and in particular is $2008 + 3 = 2011$.

Comment: @daisies I can't understand many a thing...why one of them has to be $2$

Comment: Well, the LHS is clearly an integer. The RHS is also therefore an integer, and thus the LHS has only powers of 2 in its factorization. But in that case, we know that both $x - 2004$ and $x - 2006$ are powers of 2; the only powers of 2 that differ by 2 are $2, 4$. It seems that you know the right answer - it would be helpful to me to know if I am totally off-base. Also for some reason I put $ 0 \cdot 2 = 2^0$ in my earlier comment, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: The other case I meant was $x = 2002$, so we see $-2, -4$. But this is clearly a smaller answer.

Comment: @daisies answer is 2011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the solutions wants $x, y \in \mathbb Z$, so the the LHS is an integer. Then, the RHS is an integer and in particular forces both factors in the LHS to be integer powers of 2; but we know that the only possible integer powers of 2 that differ by 2 are $2$ and $4$, so the only possible solutions are $x - 2004 = 4, x - 2006 = 2$, or $x - 2004 = -2, x - 2006 = -4$, so $x = 2008, x = 2002$ respectively. Clearly $x = 2008, y = 3$ gives the larger value of $x +y$, so we conclude that the solution is $2011$.